# Hbase1.2.1 to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hbase, bigdata

I have a table in hbase(v-1.2.1) and I want to apply some machine learning techniques on it. Therefore I want to load my table form hbase to pandas dataframe.

```
hbase(main):006:0> list
TABLE
cust_sms                                                              
1 row(s) in 0.0120 seconds
=> ["cust_sms"]
hbase(main):007:0>
```

The table name is "cust_sms" and the version of hbase is 1.2.1. I am not able to use happybase as it only works with hbase 0.9.x versions.

`

Answer (score -1):

I had written a python package to read and write pandas dataframes to and from hbase. I haven't used this package in quite sometime. You can give it a try though. The github repo is [here](https://github.com/livingstonese/pandas-hbase). The PyPi package is [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdhbase)

```
import happybase
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pdhbase as pdh
connection = None
try:
    connection = happybase.Connection('127.0.0.1')
    connection.open()
    df = pdh.read_hbase(connection, 'sample_table', 'df_key', cf='cf')
    print df
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
```